# If there is a point in a fractional value from the input whose type is number, the value is not detecting

Tags: html, reactjs, input, sum

I'm taking numbers from many inputs and summing them. However, if a number like "15." is written and a fraction is not specified after the period, the value of this entry is perceived as blank. I'm "15." When it is written, I want to detect it as 15 and include it in the total.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vJp7R.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gjAiK.png)